# Accidently use of transferFrom function

Tags: solidity, web3js

accidently we used transferFrom function in a smart contract for token transfer now tokens are stuck is there any way to recover tokens from smart contract

```
function withdrawTokens(address _to, uint256 _amount) public onlyOwner {
   Token.transferFrom(address(this), _to, _amount);
}
```

Comment: Where did you transfer the tokens to?

Comment: The contract is trying to transfer its own tokens to `_to`. It should be equivalent to `Token.transfer(_to, _amount)`. It could fail if 1/ the contract doesn't own the tokens, 2/ the token contract has a bug in `transferFrom`.